# Deselect selected item in wpf tree view (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I am using a WPF treeview, when i click on a node\item once it gets selected. When the user clicks on the selected node the second time i want this node\item to get deselected i.e. i should be able to get the event. IsSelected is not called if i click on the selected node\item that is already selected. How do i get it to work?

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding source}" Name="mytreeview">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding displaytext}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

and in my view model i have

```
 public bool IsSelected
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _isSelected; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isSelected)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                if (_isSelected)
                {
                  //my logic
                }

                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The IsSelected property is only changed when you select a new item. Clicking on the same item twice will normally have no effect. You would need to register the MouseDown event on the TreeView, and then force the item to be deselected in the code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late but I've recently had the same requirement (i.e. unselecting a selected TreeViewItem on the second click) and I solved it by declaring an event handler for the 'MouseLeftButtonUp' event in a 'Style' entry for the ItemContainerStyle of the TreeView as follows:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The event handler in the code behind was as follows:

```
private TreeViewItem prevTVI;

private void TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem tvi = (TreeViewItem)sender;
    if (tvi == this.prevTVI)
    {
        this.prevTVI = null;
        if (tvi.IsSelected)
            tvi.IsSelected = false;
    }
    else
        this.prevTVI = tvi;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Now, I would like to ask if anyone thinks this approach breaks the MVVM pattern? I personally don't think so as the event handler is only concerned with the View and its objects not anything else but I would like to hear what others have to say, especially if someone has an alternative.

Comment: are you writing an Answer to this question or asking a new question? Please see [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) questions on SO.

Comment: @techspider it is  an answer to the problem, and it suited me, but I was more interested to see what other people thought about it in relation to the MVVM design pattern

Comment: You may have to post it as a new question, giving this question are as reference.  Please refer [this article on how to write a good answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @techspider I don't think it warrants a new question. All I really wanted to do was to get other peoples opinion on my solution in regard to the MVVM design pattern (e.g. did anyone think it broke any MVVM rules). It wasn't supposed to be any big deal.

Comment: Please refer [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266756/discussion-on-meta-can-i-ask-a-question-in-an-answer)

Comment: This looks like concentrated navel gazing. All I wanted to do was elicit a response or two regarding the MVVM design pattern. I didn't expect the Spanish Inquisition.

Comment: Excellent solution, exactly what I came up with. Unfortunately the -1 grade made me ignore your solution. Really undeserved for. This is IMO the correct solution, and after spending a good few hours both trying and searching for solutions - I think this is the best that exists. Deserves more votes up.

Comment: Hi @DavidRefaeli, many thanks for your comment. I'm glad someone thought an OK solution but, can you tell me, do you think it obeys the MVVM design pattern rules? I think it does for the reasons I've mentioned but I'd like other folks views.

Comment: @RobDev You're welcome. I think you can't use MVVM here, as Aaron from the selected answer mentioned - selecting the same item again does not trigger the property. I.e. you cannot move the same logic from the MouseUp in code-behind to the IsSelected in ItemVM... So you have to break away from MVVM here. I would however move the selected item (your prevTVI) from the code-behind to the ViewModel containing the TreeView (in general, not specific node) so it will be accessible by rest of ViewModels logic.

Comment: Hi @DavidRefaeli, thanks for your reply. Regarding the MVVM thing, I thought that one of the ideas of the design pattern was to separate View processing from ViewModel processing i.e. anything that was solely concerned with the View, like TreeViewItem and MouseLeftButtonUp event, could be referred to in the 'code behind' without breaking the MVVM rules. However, I could be wrong.

Comment: @RobDev I'm not an expert on MVVM, but I think you are right. Though theoretically selecting an item could trigger some event/change in the underlying data objects (in VM or M). In that case you would be theoretically breaking away from MVVM, simply because you have to.

Comment: Hi @DavidRefaeli, I'm not an expert on MVVM either (I'm not sure that there are that many of them about) but thanks for your view on the subject, it's much appreciated. I suspect that the MVVM design pattern is always going to have grey areas that people will interpret to the best of their judgement at the time. It's a pity that there doesn't seem to be an absolutely definitive set of rules but maybe that would be too inflexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value != _isSelected)
```

Assuming that the UI is even trying to set something, that line is blocking your toggle logic. Something like this should fix at least that part.

```
    set
    {
        if (value != _isSelected)
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
        else if(_isSelected)
        {
            IsSelected = false;
        }
    }
```

Otherwise the UI is checking the selection before setting the value and you'll need to handle it through some other user interaction like handling deselection on click.